# SQL Select Create Colmun

Tags: sql

Sorry to ask, but my sql sucks.
Im carrying out a simple: select startdate from table
startdate returns a date, but I also need to get the year out of startdate to a new column, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add calculated columns directly to the `SELECT`. Note that it doesn't create *physical* columns; it's just used for that query.

```
SELECT StartDate, YEAR(StartDate) AS Year
FROM table
```